# How to store objects in a vector?

Tags: matlab

Basically what I want to do is to define an empty vector, and then fill it up with some objects in a for loop, like

```
status = [];
while(sweepLine.y > 0)
    for i = 1 : m
       isSweeped = IsBeingSweeped(Sections(i), sweepLine);
       if(isSweeped == 1)
       status(i) = Sections(i);
     end
     sweepLine.y = sweepLine.y - 1;
 end
```

However, matlab simply tells me the error like, 
The following error occurred converting from Section to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from Section is not possible.

Error in tryGOX (line 41)
        status(i) = Sections(i);

If I want to do the same thing in Java, probably I would write

```
Section[] status = new Section[10];
while(sweepLine.y > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
       isSweeped = IsBeingSweeped(Sections[i], sweepLine);
       if(isSweeped == 1)
       status[i] = Sections[i];
     }
    sweepLine.y = sweepLine.y - 1;
 }
```

How could I do this in Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: Are you missing an `end` for the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of lacking information. Some guesses:

`status` is a function. Don't use it as a variable. Change its name and try if the error persists.

You said `Sections` contains **objects**. You can't store objects in a double array. Use a [**cell array**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) instead:

```
sectionStatus{i} = Sections(i);
```

Or even better:

```
sectionStatus{ii} = Sections(ii);
```

as `i` is the imaginary unit and it could cause troubles, when you overwrite it. (Though not so much troubles, if any, in newer versions of Matlab).

---

**A little more sophisticated approach would be to use** [**structs**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/struct.html)

```
getobjname = @(x) inputname(1);
sectionStatus = struct;

while(sweepLine.y > 0)
    for ii = 1 : m
       isSweeped = IsBeingSweeped(Sections(ii), sweepLine);
       if(isSweeped == 1)
          sectionStatus.( getobjname(Sections(ii)) ) = Sections(ii);
       end
       sweepLine.y = sweepLine.y - 1;
    end
 end
```

which will give you a struct with all your sections by there class-instances' names. Which I guess, is actually the way how the variable `Sections` is built up.

Answer (score 0):

you can pre-allocate if you know the size.

```
status= zeros(size);
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you know the size you can do:

```
status = zeros(N);
```

or:

```
status(N) = 0;
```

If you don't know the size, then in your for loop, you can write:

```
status(end+1) = Sections(i);
```